Nginx config and certbot for EJS app on subdomain
I have a webpage, let's say example.com. It is a JS / html based webpage, nothing too special. It is running on IP1 using nginx.
Files are under
    /nginx/html/example.com
I created another webpage with the subdomain of extra.example.com. This is also on the same server with IP1, but under a different folder:
    /nginx/html/extra.example.com and this is an EJS app. App listens on port 3000.
Both websites are loading and working as expected except for www.extra.example.com. (extra.example.com loads)
extra.example.com's config file under
    nginx/conf.d/extra.example.com.conf
server { listen 80; server_name extra.example.com www.extra.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
} `

nginx.conf has this:
    include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
So it should pull the config for include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
My first question is how to make www.extra.example.com to load just like extra.example.com? I might be missing some nginx config, but I can't seem to figure.
My second question is about certificate.
example.com have let's encrypt certificate for     example.com www.example.com; with the specific root folder. Connection is secure.
I'd like to have the same for the EJS extra.example.com.
However if I try to run
    sudo certbot certonly --cert-name extra.example.com -d extra.example.com -d www.extra.example.com
Even if I choose the option to add the root folder, it is not working. The config file is not getting updated and so no certificate.
What am I missing here?
Here is my dns setup:
 Type | name | data  
A | @ | IP1     
A | exta | IP1     
NS | @ | ns55.domaincontrol.com     
NS | @ | ns56.domaincontrol.com     
CNAME | * | example.com     
CNAME | www | example.com     
CNAME | _domainconnect | _domainconnect......     
SOA | @ | Primary nameserver: ns55.....
Thanks!
